# RADHTMLChart and Stacked Column Series Code Behind Population

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts, telerik, reporting

I have an issue that i have been struggling with for long time now,

I created a reporting application where it has classes that represents objects from DB, in this case they are Projects and Resources
I want the chart to preview each project as a series and the resources of each project as series items in a stacked view with a Y value for each resource as the house consumed by each resource on this particular project

[image: Projects And Resources]

I have tried everything possible to get it working, read all Telerik documents regarding this and its not working
Now i got them to show as they weren't showing correctly previously, but the legend of the RADHTMLChart shows only the series names, i want each item in the column to show the name of the resource or even the legend to show the name of the resource not the name of project, Please note that i did hide the legend because basically its showing names of projects instead of names of resources

the code for populating it below:

```
Dim Projects As New List(Of Project)
    Projects = GetProjects()
    For Each nProject As Project In Projects
        Dim npChartSeries As New ColumnSeries
        npChartSeries.Stacked = True
        'npChartSeries.StackType = HtmlChart.Enums.HtmlChartStackType.Normal
        ' npChartSeries.GroupName = nProject.Name

        Dim npAxisItem As New AxisItem
        npAxisItem.LabelText = nProject.Name
        If nProject.Resources IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each nEmp As Employee In nProject.Resources

                Dim npSeriesItem As New SeriesItem
                npSeriesItem.Name = nEmp.Username

                npSeriesItem.YValue = nEmp.TotalTimesheets
                npChartSeries.Items.Add(npSeriesItem)
            Next
        End If

        RadHtmlChart2.PlotArea.XAxis.Items.Add(npAxisItem)
        RadHtmlChart2.PlotArea.Series.Add(npChartSeries)

    Next
```

---

Using the ASP.Net chart i was able to achieve what i want but here its totally not working, your help is highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: I haven't used that tool, but I wanted to note that I've had better luck getting Telerik help from Telerik than using StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually our subscription was for an earlier Telerik DevCraft suite and already expired so i don't know if would get support on this or not